# After adding Extension I am getting Lexical and PreProcessor error Xcode 9.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

Hi all I have added Notification service extension and added target properly . When I build the project I am getting lexical error .

Tried cleaning archive , Restart Xcode , Changing framework path .

**If I remove the Notification Service Extension then everything is working , When I am adding the notification extension to my project I am getting this error .**

If anyone crossed this issue . Let me know what I am doing wrong .

[image]

What I did?

File -> New -> Target -> Notification Service Extension added under project.

Made changes on the extension class file.

```
self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];
    NSString *imgUrl = request.content.userInfo[@"data"][@"attachment-url"];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl];
    NSError *error;
    UNNotificationAttachment *icon = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"image" URL:imageURL options:nil error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error while storing image attachment in notification: %@", error);
    }
    if (icon)
    {
        self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = @[icon];
    }
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
```

Comment: are you using cocoa pods ?

Comment: Yes @TejaNandamuri I am using

Comment: do you have the target specified in podfile for your extension ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri how to add target to pod file ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar: please read the CocoaPods docs for basic questions on how to use it: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally:**

The issue is because of the created extension carrying the header path as Parent file header path , So if you mentioned any pod file header path in you prefix then it will give you the error , So remove the header path and kept it as empty .

**Build Setting -> HeaderPath -> Remove it .**

Make sure you have selected the extension target while removing the path .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoa pods, Edit your pod file, and create two types of pods, one for main target application, one for extension target.

```
def application_pods
use_frameworks!
#list of frameworks you use in your main target
pod 'UIImageView+WebCache'
end


def extension_pods
use_frameworks!
#list of frameworks you would use in your extension
pod 'UIImageView+WebCache'    
end


target 'YourMainTargetName' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
# Pods for YourTargetName
application_pods
end

target 'NotificationService' do
extension_pods
end
```

If you dont use pods, then you need to select the UIImageView+WebCache .h,.m files and in the Target membership section, you need to check the extension target checkbox.

Comment: Even if I didn't use any pod file for my extension I have to do ?

Comment: you dont need a separate pod file for extension, if you use pods, you have one pod file for everything.

Comment: If you dont use pods, then you need to select the UIImageView+WebCache file and in the Target membership section, you need to check the extension target checkbox.

Comment: I have added the extension , but I didn't made any changes , So do you think that I have to add the all the application pods need to come under the extension pod ?

Comment: Is this from the `SDWebImage` framework? Then the pod line should be: `pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'`

Comment: you are right @Koen, it should be replaced with right library name. I just mentioned it as reference.

Comment: @KishoreKumar you dont have to add all application pods under target extension pods, you only need to add what you need in your target extension which in your case is either SDWebImage or whatever the framework that contains the imageview+cache fiel

Comment: If I update the sdWebimage to 4.0 then I am getting this error .[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SDWebImage":
  In Podfile:
    QMChatViewController was resolved to 0.4.1.1, which depends on
      SDWebImage (~> 3.6)

    SDWebImage (~> 4.0)

Comment: The QMChatViewController is depending on that framework

Comment: you dont have to specify the version or update it, use the one that is compatible to your project.

Comment: Even though still error remains @TejaNandamuri , I tried all the solution

Comment: please update your question with your error and what you tried.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri is this because of target issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168415/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-teja-nandamuri).